# run a query against android sqlite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

So, I'm new to android dev and I'm developing my first app. This app uses SQLite to store some data in order to generate a few reports and later sync to a cloud... So far debugging has been a real pain in the ass because i need to write a query inside the app launch in order to get a better view of whats going on with the tables...

I would like to know how can I run a query against my android app database?

please notice that i do want to know how my app to query its database, that part i got covered.

What i need to know is how to use a tool on my dev machine to query the database! My dev machine is a MAC, running OSX latest version...

Answer (score 1):

You can use adb shell from your Mac to launch SQLite on the Android device, then run SQLite queries from there: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite

Comment: This is the way to go.